# PDF is corrupted after compressing with Ghostscript

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

Is there a way to revert a PDF after it is compressed? Every PDF is getting corrupted when it gets compressed with our script, which runs

```
gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS="/$mode" -dNOPAUSE \
   -dBATCH $verbose -sOutputFile="$file-new" "$file" |
  tee -a $log
sizeold=$(wc -c "$file" | cut -d' ' -f1)
sizenew=$(wc -c "$file-new" | cut -d' ' -f1)
difference=$((sizenew-sizeold))
```

Comment: After some research with the person that made the Script. I found out the compressor is have a compatibility issue with ES7